# Значение return

Tags: c++

Я не понимаю, куда и что возвращает оператор return. В функции main это говорит о завершении программы с кодом 0 (успешно), а что происходит в других ситуациях?

Comment: Честно говоря, ответ проще нагуглить. Про это есть много туториалов, а вы просите написать еще один лично для вас.

Answer (score -2):

Завершает выполнение функции и возвращает значение в вызывающую функцию (или в операционную систему при передаче управления из функции main).

Comment: Что такое "элемент управления"?

Answer (score -2):

Если попробовать присвоить переменной значение из функции, то для этого и нужен оператор return. Вот пример:

```
int p = 3;

int piz(int mus) {
    return mus * 2;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    p = piz(p);
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если сделать тип функции `void`, то будет ошибка.